# Inject Dependencies at runtime using Google Guice

Tags: guice

I'm thinking of using Guice for DI in my app where I should be able to swap the implementations at runtime. An example is provided below to illustrate the requirement:

```java
class ValidationEngine {
   public void validate(ValidationService vs) {}
}

class Client1_ValidationService implements ValidationService {}
class Client2_ValidationService implements ValidationService {}
```

One of the above implementation should be bound to validate function at runtime based on client name, say Client1 or Client2

I thought of changing the ValidationEngine like this:

```java
class ValidationEngine {   
    @Inject 
    @Named("vServicee") ValidationService vs;

    public void validate() {
         vs.validate()
    }
}
```

The problem with the above approach is that the parameter to the @Named annotation is static; in fact annotations don't accept runtime values. Are there any other approaches in Guice to solve this kind of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [Injector.createChildInjector](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Injector.html) to create your own injector for each `ValidationService` implementation:

```java
Injector client1Injector = injector.createChildInjector(new Module() {
    @Override
    public void configure(final Binder binder) {
        binder
           .bind(ValidationService.class)
           .to(Client1_ValidationService.class);
        }
    });

ValidationEngine client1Engine = 
    client1Injector.getInstance(ValidationEngine.class)
```

But that implies that you have to somehow manage all child injectors.

Comment: This seems to be fine. Just to clarify the things - so if I have 5 clients, I'll end up with 5 injectors. And storing them in HashMap may help to get the injectors using the client ID. Is that a right approach?

Comment: @giri_col Seems so. You have to keep injector for each `ValidationService` implementation. Something like that - https://gist.github.com/KetothXupack/b4f6786a1590c7a2466be5f9523a564a

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass in configuration information to your Guice module via it's constructor.

Pseudocode:

```
main() { // your main method
    flags = parseFlags()
    injector = guice.createInjector(new MyModule(flags.validator))
}

MyModule { // your guice module
    constructor(validator): this.validator = validator;
    configure() {
        Class<ValidatorService> client_validator;
        if this.validator == KNOWN_CLIENT1:
            client_validator = Client1_ValidationService.class
        else:
            client_validator = Client2_ValidationService.class
        bind(ValidationService.class).to(client_validator);
    }
}
```

Guice cautions against this, as it increases the surface area for you to test. https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AvoidConditionalLogicInModules

Answer (score 0):

1) Inject directly by injector with names, like:

```java
@Inject
private Injector injector;

public ValidationService getValidationServiceForClient(String clientName) {
    return injector.getInstance(Key.get(ValidationService.class, Names.named(clientName)));
}
```

2) Another way:

```java
public class ValidationServiceProviderImpl implements ValidationServiceProvider {

    @Inject
    @Named("ClientA")
    private ValidationService clientAValidationService;

    @Inject
    @Named("ClientB")
    private ValidationService clientBValidationService;

    public ValidationService getValidationServiceForClient(String clientName) {
        switch (clientName) {
            case "ClientA": return clientAValidationService;
            case "ClientB": return clientBValidationService;
        }
        return null; // return default validationService for any other client
    }
}

public interface ValidationServiceProvider {
    ValidationService getValidationServiceForClient(String clientName);
}
```

Configuration:

```java
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ValidationService.class)
            .annotatedWith(Names.named("ClientA"))
            .to(ClientA_ValidationService.class);
        bind(ValidationService.class)
            .annotatedWith(Names.named("ClientB"))
            .to(ClientB_ValidationService.class);
        bind(ValidationServiceProvider.class)
            .to(ValidationServiceProviderImpl.class);
    }
});
```

Example using provider:

```java
ValidationServiceProvider validationServiceFactory = 
    injector.getInstance(ValidationServiceProvider.class);
ValidationService clientA = 
    validationServiceFactory.getValidationServiceForClient("ClientA");
ValidationService clientB = 
    validationServiceFactory.getValidationServiceForClient("ClientB");
```

Example using injector directly:

```java
ValidationService clientA = 
    injector.getInstance(Key.get(ValidationService.class, Names.named("ClientA")));
ValidationService clientB =
    injector.getInstance(Key.get(ValidationService.class, Names.named("ClientB")));
```